# Import Table (IT) vs Import Address Table (IAT)

Tags: c, portable-executable

I've been trying to parse/display the information in the Import Address Table (IAT) of a process after it is loaded and running. I understand API calls in programs jump to the relevant point in the IAT, which then jumps to the actual function in the loaded DLL's.

Is it correct that the IAT can be found by reading the PE header and following the OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1] pointer, to the array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs. Then following the *FirstThunk* pointers. Whereas the  *OriginalFirstThunk* pointers here, will give you the original Import Table (IT)?

I have also tried following the OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[12] pointer in the PE header, but this was even less successful.

I've been testing this by trying to parse this structure for notepad.exe (32bit), using ReadProcessMemory from another process.

Here's the rough C-psuedocode for what I'm doing:

```
char buf[128];

// get first import descriptor
readMemory(&import, procImgBase + DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));

// get dll name 
readMemory(buf, import.Name + procImgBase, 127);
printf("libname: %s\n", buf);

// get first function name
DWORD iltAddress = 0;
readMemory(&iltAddress, import.FirstThunk + procImgBase, 4);
readMemory(buf, iltAddress + procImgBase, 127);
printf("fname: %s\n", libName + 2); // <-- the +2 for the 2byte 'hint' of import lookup table entries
```

If, on the 3rd to last line, i replace it with import.OriginalFirstThunk instead of FirstThunk, it will print everything as expected. I must be missing something conceptually, and so I was wondering if anyone could clarify what this is, for me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're heading the right direction. Some notes:

- The DataDirectory gives you an offset
  to an array of
  IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR which is
  terminated by an entry of all zeros.
  There will be one
  IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR for each DLL
  that is imported
- The
  IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR has offsets
  to 2 arrays of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA, one
  that maintains offsets to the names
  of the imported functions
  (OriginalFirstThunk) and another that
  now has the actual addresses of the
  functions (FirstThunk)

Since your executable is running, the IAT should contain the actual address of the function rather than an RVA to a name entry.

You could do something like this instead:

```
DWORD rva_to_name_of_function = 0;
DWORD address_of_function = 0;

// get the RVA of the IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME entry
readMemory(&rva_to_name, import.OriginalFirstThunk + procImgBase, 4);

// copy the name of the import
readMemory(buf, rva_to_name + procImgBase + 2, 127);

// get the actual address that was filled in by the loader
readMemory(&address_of_function, import.FirstThunk + procImgBase, 4);

printf("fname: %s address: %X", buf, address_of_function);
```

Take a look at this article for some helpful details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx

Comment: Thanks! makes sense now. I guess I should have realised when the values I was getting back, looked like valid addresses and not RVA's.

Comment: @Eric Rahm, are you sure about your first bullet-point? In `winnt.h`, the optional header structs define `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES];`, not `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR DataDirectory[IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES];`

Comment: This is where I'm currently stuck... I'm up to getting the data directories, but how to load them in the correct structs to get the DLL names from the IAT or ILT or INT is currently blocking me.

Answer (score 4):

Eric gave a good answer, here are some additional clarifications:

> I understand API calls in programs jump to the relevant point in the IAT, which then jumps to the actual function in the loaded DLL's.

The program uses a CALL PTR DS:[IAT-ADDRESS] that reads from an address in the IAT to determine where the program is at runtime.

> Whereas the OriginalFirstThunk pointers here, will give you the original Import Table (IT)?

The OriginalFirstThunk pointers point you at the Import Lookup table (ILT).  If you open up the binary on disk, the ILT and the IAT are identical; both contain RVA's to function name strings.  Once the program has been loaded, the IAT's entries (in memory) are overwritten with the addresses of the imported functions.

In my experience, the best source of information on the import table and all of its attendant data structures is the PE specification itself.  If you read patiently through the section on imports, all will be made clear.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463125

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I've read and re-read the MSDN documentation, but my brain seems to be wired in a different way to the authors - I just couldn't make sense of this part of it. The way you word things is clearer :-)

Comment: That pecoff docx really irks me. It has a ton of info, but has some really hurtful gaps in it... Misinformation too. Their "virtually all executables" clause for having `.idata` is not so nearly all-encompassing...